# Some questions about Weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im reading chapter11 of Carothers' Real Analysis, 1ed talking about Weierstrass Approximation Theorem. Here is an introduction,
[image]

1. How to explain the "how" there?
2. Since q is the polynomial approximating f with rational coefficients, that is to say there exist two approximation methods(precisely, one is p containing at leat one irrational coefficient and the other is q) or in other words, Weierstrass approximation theorem guarantee the existence of polynomial but not its coefficients being rational?

Comment: 1. $\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n r_k x^k -\sum_{i=1}^n p_k x^k\Vert\le (|a|+|b|+1)^n\sum_{i=1}^n |r_k-p_k|$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: What are |a|,|b|? Where do they come from?

Comment: Read your Theorem :)

Comment: @DavidMitra: "n" means that both p and q contain finite items?

Comment: Yes, I assumed the (fixed) polynomial in question had degree $n$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: If so, what's going on next?

Comment: Well...  Fix the "$p_k$" polynomial. Let $\epsilon>0$. For each $k$, choose $r_k$ close enough to $p_k$ so that the sum is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: using this, we can build rk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. This follows from the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ be any polynomial with real coefficients and fix an $\epsilon > 0$. Note that for any $q(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n q_k x^k$ and any $x \in [a,b]$
   $$
       |p(x) - q(x)| \leq \sum_{k=0}^n |a_k - q_k| |x|^k \leq \sum_{k=0}^n |a_k - q_k| M^k
   $$
   where $M = \max(|a|,|b|)$. So you can show that $\|p-q\|_\infty < \epsilon$ by, for each $k \in\{0,\ldots,n\}$, choosing a $q_k \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
   $$
       |a_k - q_k| < \frac{\epsilon}{(n+1)M^k}.
   $$
2. The way it's stated in the passage you've selected, no: the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem doesn't say anything about the coefficients of the approximating polynomials. However, we've just said quite a bit! In fact, it's not difficult to combine Weierstrass's theorem with 1. to conclude that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ -- the set of polynomials with rational coefficients -- is dense in $C[a,b]$. Do you see how?

   In fact, this is exactly what the author is saying when he points out that $C[a,b]$ is separable! I'm not sure how generally separability is defined in Carother, but a metric space $M$ is **separable** if it contains a subset $S$ such that

   - $S$ is countable
   - $S$ is dense in $M$ (*i.e.*, every element of $M$ is the limit of a sequence $\{s_n\}$ of elements $s_n$ in $S$) under the metric within $M$

   (Typically such a subset $S$ is called a **countably dense** subspace of $M$, naturally!)
   Here $M = C[a,b]$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ (or metric $d(f_1,f_2) = \|f_1-f_2\|_\infty$), and $S = \mathbb{Q}[x]$. If you can show that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is uniformly dense in $C[a,b]$ as I recommended above, then you've also shown that $C[a,b]$ is separable. (Side note: How do you know that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is countable? If you don't immediately see an argument, now would be a good time to prove that this is true.)

Edit: Here's how to conclude explicitly that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is dense in $C[a,b]$ given what we now know.

Let $f \in C[a,b]$. Assume $\{p_k\}$ is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$. Accordingly, if we fix an $\epsilon > 0$, we know that there exists $K_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \geq K_\epsilon$
$$
    \|f - p_k\|_\infty < \epsilon/2.
$$
At the same time, by 1. we know that for each $k$ there exists a sequence $\{q_{k,i}\}$ of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $q_{k,i} \to p_k$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ as $i \to \infty$. Hence for each $k$, there exists $I_{k,\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that and for all $i \geq I_{k,\epsilon}$
$$
    \|p_k - q_{k,i}\|_\infty < \epsilon/2.
$$
Set $k = K_{\epsilon}$, set $i = I_{k,\epsilon}$, and then conclude that there exists a polynomial $q := q_{k,i}$ with rational coefficients such that
$$
    \|f - q\|_\infty = \|(f-p_k)+(p_k-q)\|_\infty \leq \|f-p_k\|_\infty + \|p_k - q\|_\infty < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.
$$

Comment: Definition of Separable in Carothers is the same as you post here. Although the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem doesn't say anything about the coefficients of the approximating polynomials, from this proof, we can use polynomials with only rational coefficients to approximate function f, is that right?

Comment: Yes. I know how to show $Q$[x] is countable.

Comment: @Frank_W: That's correct, and I'd highly encourage you to fill in the details. Say $f \in C[a,b]$. Using the theorem, you can choose a sequence $\{p_k\}_k$ within $\mathbb{R}[x]$ that converges to $f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$. By 1., you now know that, for each $k$, there also exists a sequence $\{q_{k,i}\}$ of polynomials with rational coefficients converging uniformly to $p_k$ on $[a,b]$. How can you choose elements in the sequences $\{q_{k,i}\}$ to form a sequence of polynomials with rational coefficients that converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$?

Comment: @Frank_W: Ah ok. Great! I figured you knew how to but didn't want to miss an opportunity to point out a useful exercise. `:)`

Comment: @Dan: I know the existence of {$q_{k,i}$} which has been showed in this proof. But actually I do not know how to choose this {$q_{k,i}$}.

Comment: @Frank_W: Ok I'll update my post with a sketch.

Comment: Since n is finite, then {$q_{k}$} is a finite union of countable sets, so $Q$[x]is countable. Is that right?

Comment: @Frank_W: I'm not sure what you mean by $\{q_k\}$ here, but no: you usually prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is countable by invoking the fact that it's a *countable* union of countable sets (which ones?), which are also countable sets. Of course, knowing that the latter fact is true is necessary to prove the former.

Edit: Ah you might've meant $\{q_{k,i}\}$, but that's just a sequence converging to $p_k$. So the fact that it contains countably many polynomials doesn't say anything about the cardinality of the whole set $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness and patience, Dan. It really make sense greatly.

Comment: @Frank_W: I'm happy to hear it!

Comment: Dan, Bernstein polynomials is a method to choose {$q_{k,i}$}, is that right?

Comment: @Frank_W: The Bernstein basis polynomials $b_{n,k}(x)$ have rational coefficients, but whether or not $B_n(f)(x)$ has rational coefficients for $f \in C[0,1]$ depends more on the values of $f$ than properties of $b_{n,k}$. (The coefficient of $b_{n,k}(x)$ in $B_n(f)(x)$ looks like $f(k/n)$, which may or may not be rational.) Now, you can of course approximate each of the polynomial $B_n(f)(x)$ by polynomials with rational coefficients, but the same could be said about any sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $f$.

Comment: I see. You are right.